# The difference between "A" and "A"[0]

Tags: go

I write this code for convert `TEXT` to `BINARY`

```
fmt.Printf("%s\n", fmt.Sprintf("%08b", "A"))
```

and not work, print message: `%!b(string=0000000A)`

but when i changed `"A"` to `"A"[0]` work fine:

```
fmt.Printf("%s\n", fmt.Sprintf("%08b", "A"[0]))
```

output is `01000001`

what is difference between above statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Golang differentiates strings from bytes.

`"A"` is a string, technically [a read-only slice of bytes](https://blog.golang.org/strings). `"A"[0]` is the first byte in this sequence, whose value is 0x41.

You asked to print first a string (`"A"`), then secondly a byte (`"A"[0]`), in a field of eight characters using binary digits. Your first output was funny because you tried to print a string as if it were some kind of byte value. But a sequence of one byte is not the same as a single byte. Your second output was more natural, since you grabbed the first byte of the string (at index 0), obtaining 0x41.

Comment: Actually, "A"[0] is a byte, not a rune.

Comment: Omg that was embarrassing. Thanks. Fixed the answer.